# I am trying to download JXTA 2.7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-me, jxta

I am trying to download JXTA 2.7 from this site http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicaljxta/files/ . When I unzip the content I see diffrent classes than those I have seen in JXTA 2.5. Do you know why?

Comment: Because it's a different version?...

Comment: I am treying to read this tutorial and I am testing the examples there.

Comment: I am trying to find the methos "NetworkManager.RecursiveDelete" since Netbeans can not find it.

Answer (score 1):

Because many things changed since JXSE 2.6 and 2.7. Visit the tutorial section and read the "Programmer's Guides". Those will inform you about the changes done. http://jxse.kenai.com/Tutorials/Tutorials.html Probably you are working with new binaries (2.6 / 2.7) and an old tutorial (2.5).